# A user with db_datareader role has SELECT access to all table. How do I exclude one table?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL2008R02 database user added to the data reader role. This user can SELECT all tables. But I want to him to restrict him from one table. How do I do this? I do not want to run GRANT SELECT individually on all tables except one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DENY permission on the one table, for example:

```
DENY SELECT ON myTable TO myUser
```

DENY "permissions" are available in SQL 2008 onwards.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188338.aspx