# MSSQL - Grant Select rights to all tables except one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I have a database where a generic user has the "public" and "db_datareader" permission so that user can select from all tables/views.

Now I have a specific case where there is a single table in that Database that only a specific user has access to.

Is there a simple way to exclude that one table without having to grant the generic user specific rights on all other tables/views?
This question: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978536/a-user-with-db-datareader-role-has-select-access-to-all-table-how-do-i-exclude) talks about the "DENY" rule

Secondly, if I use this table in a view.. will the select of the view fail if you don't have access to all tables in the view definition?

Thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `DENY` is the way to go here. Yes, if the table is used in `view` the user will be able to query it.

The following example code demonstrates it:

```
--DROP USER IF EXISTS [StackOverflow];
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Data];
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[DataDeny];
--DROP VIEW IF EXISTS [dbo].[vw_Data];

CREATE USER [StackOverflow] WITHOUT LOGIN;

EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_datareader'
                     ,@membername = 'StackOverflow';

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data]
(
    [column] INT
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Data]
VALUES (1);

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataDeny]
(
    [column] INT
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataDeny]
VALUES (2);

GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Data]
AS
SELECT [column]
FROM [dbo].[Data]
UNION ALL
SELECT [column]
FROM [dbo].[DataDeny];

GO

DENY SELECT ON [dbo].[DataDeny] TO [StackOverflow]

GO

EXECUTE AS USER  = 'StackOverflow';

SELECT [column] AS [read]
FROM [dbo].[Data];

SELECT [column] AS [not_Read]
FROM [dbo].[DataDeny]

SELECT [column] AS [read]
FROM [dbo].[vw_Data];

REVERT;
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the table has to have the same owner as the view for the permissions to be implicitly granted. If they are in a different database, then database ownership chaining needs to be enabled on the database the table is located in.

Comment: @gotqn Apologies for opening this up again but I encounter a strange thing that I thought would work..I set the DENY permission for a spefic user on the table that they are not to query, but when I use it in a view its not denied. Should it not be denied as well since it cannot read all source tables?

Comment: @DirkR. Yes, that's exactly what my example shows. If the table is used in a view, the user is able to see the data even if one is not able to query it directly from the table.

Comment: @gotqn I just re-read your answer and indeed that is what you state in your first line. My apologies. Is there however a way to hide the data also in the view? Otherwise I'll just have to Deny the user on the view completely as well and only provide another user access to it.. (which also works ofcourse)

Comment: @DirkR. What version of SQL Server you are using? In SQL Server 2016 you can use row-level security (check this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @gotqn Sadly 2014 :-) Thanks for the information tho!